# preg_match_all doesn't return the expected value

Tags: php, regex

I've wrote a relatively simple code to extract email addresses from a log file, based on a specific pattern; i'm only interested in cases when people sent emails to themselves.

This show in the log like this: `<%EMAIL%> -> <%SAME-EMAIL%>`

> Clarification:
>
> The <%EMAIL%> represents an email address inside "<>" characters, followed by " -> ", then followed by the **same** email address. This pattern may (or may not) occur multiple times in a line.

```
for example:

<somename@somesite.com> -> <somename@somesite.com> should match
<somename@somesite.com> -> <othername@othersite.com> should NOT match
```

the code i currently use:

```
$regx = '/(<[\S]+>)\s->\s\1/';
while ( !feof($myfile) )
{
    $line = fgets($myfile);
    $tmpline = $line;
    if ( preg_match_all($regx, $tmpline, $tmp) )
    {
        $data[$caught++] = $tmp;
    }
}
fclose($myfile);
```

My problem is, the `$tmp` array doesn't store the actual addresses only the " -> " substring.
My output (`print_r($data)`) looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] =>  -> 
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

)
...
```

I suspect, the problem lies in my regex pattern, but unfortunately I'm not yet capable of identifying it.

Please help.

**Closing statement:**

The output was correct all long, but the emails were inside <> characters, and my browser tried to parse them as HTML or XML, so they wouldn't appear when echoing them out :@

The solution was hiding in the view-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$data = 
    preg_match_all('/<(\S+)>\s->\s<\1>/', file_get_contents($filename), $m)
    ? $m[1]
    : array()
;
print_r($data);
```

[Demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/vCd5Q7)

---

Another version using `fgets()`.

```
$data = array();
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
while (false !== $row = fgets($fp)) {
    if (preg_match_all('/<(\S+)>\s->\s<\1>/', $row, $m)) {
        foreach ($m[1] as $email) {
            $data[] = $email;
        }
    }
}
if (!feof($fp)) {
    exit('Error');
}
print_r($data);
```

[Demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/pQNQ95)

Comment: Seems nice, but the log files are extremely large (over 500k lines!), and as i recall, the file_get_contents would take too much resources. This is why I'm using a per line approach.

Comment: Thank you. As it seems, my original solution was correct all long; I'm accepting yours, because it's a bit faster. The output was correct In your, and My case too, but the emails were inside <> characters, and my browser tried to parse them as HTML or XML, so they wouldn't appear when echoing them out :@ Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you already have the solution. Not sure if this is an automated task or a one-time query. I usually use notepad++ (or a similar editor) for this kind of task which has excellent regexp replacement functionality, 500k lines should be no problem.